# NoSuchMethodError The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have been developing an app like uber, and I'm facing this problem when I choose one of autocomplete addresses list in the destination search bar.

Here are my main screen codes:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:topride/AllScreens/searchScreen.dart';
import 'package:topride/AllWidgets/Divider.dart';
import 'package:topride/Assistants/AssistantMethods.dart';
import 'package:topride/DataHandler/appData.dart';
import 'package:topride/AllWidgets/progressDialog.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  static const String idScreen = "mainScreen";

  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}


class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();

   GoogleMapController newgoogleMapController ;

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey=new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  List<LatLng> pLineCoordinates=[];
  Set<Polyline>polyLineSet ={};


   Position currentPosition;
  var geoLocator = Geolocator();
  double bottomPaddingOfMap = 0;

  Set<Marker> markersSet = {};
  Set<Circle> circlesSet = {};



  void locatePosition()async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
    currentPosition=position;
    LatLng latLngPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(target: latLngPosition,zoom: 14);
    newgoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    String address=await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position,context);
    print("This is Your Address ::"+ address);


  }


  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );


  @override



  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Maine Screen"),
      ),

      drawer: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        width: 255.0,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              //drawer header
              Container(
                height: 165.0,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/user_icon.png",
                      height: 65.0,width: 65.0,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text("Profile Name", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0,fontFamily: "Brand Bolt"),),

                          SizedBox(height: 6.0,),
                          Text("View Profile"),

                        ],
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              DividerWidget(),
              SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
              //drawer Body Button
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.history),
                title: Text("History",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.person),
                title: Text("View Profile",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                title: Text("About",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
              ),


            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),

      body: Stack(
        children: [
          GoogleMap(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottomPaddingOfMap),
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
            initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,

            myLocationEnabled: true,
            zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            zoomControlsEnabled: true,
            polylines: polyLineSet,
            markers: markersSet,
            circles: circlesSet,

            onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){

       _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
       newgoogleMapController = controller;
       locatePosition();

       setState(() {
         bottomPaddingOfMap=300.0;
       });



            },
          ),

          // Hamburger Button fo drawer
          Positioned(
            top: 25.0,
            left: 22.0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){
             scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();

              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                      spreadRadius: 0.5,
                      offset: Offset(0.7,0.7),
                    ),
                  ],

                ),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  child: Icon(Icons.menu, color: Colors.black,),
                  radius: 20.0,

                ),

              ),
            ),
          ) ,
          Positioned(
            left: 0.00,
            right: 0.00,
            bottom: 0.00,
            child: Container(
              height: 300.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(18.0),topRight: Radius.circular(15.0)),
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  blurRadius: 16.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.5,
                  offset: Offset(0.7,0.7),

                ),],

              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(height: 6.0),
                    Text("Hi there,",style: TextStyle(fontSize:  10.0),),
                    Text("Where to ?,",style: TextStyle(fontSize:  20.0, fontFamily: "Brand Bolt"),),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                    
                    GestureDetector(

                      onTap: ()async{
                        var res = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>SearchScreen()));
                        if (res=="obtainDirection"){

                          await getPlaceDirection();
                        }
                      },

                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            blurRadius: 6.0,
                            spreadRadius: 0.5,
                            offset: Offset(0.7,0.7),

                          ),],

                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.blue,),
                              SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
                              Text("Search Drop off"),
                            ],),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.home,color: Colors.grey,),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation != null ?
                                    Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation.placeName:
                                  "Add Home"
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            Text("Your Living Home Address",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 12.0),),

                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),

                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    DividerWidget(),
                    SizedBox(height: 16.0),

                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.work,color: Colors.grey,),
                        SizedBox(width: 12.0),
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("Add Work"),
                            SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                            Text("Your Office Address",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54,
                                fontSize: 12.0),),

                          ],
                        ),

                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );

  }
  Future<void> getPlaceDirection() async{
    var initialPos =Provider.of<AppData>(context,listen: false).pickUpLocation;
    var finalPos =Provider.of<AppData>(context,listen: false).dropOffLocation;

    var pickUpLatLng = LatLng(initialPos.latitude, initialPos.longitude);
    var dropOffLatLng = LatLng(finalPos.latitude, finalPos.longitude);

    showDialog(context: context,

        builder: (BuildContext context)=> ProgressDialog (message:"please wait...")
    );
    var details = await AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails(pickUpLatLng, dropOffLatLng);

    Navigator.pop(context);

    print("This is Encoding Points :: ");
    print(details.encodingPoints);
    PolylinePoints polylinePoints=PolylinePoints();
    List<PointLatLng> decodedPolyLinePointsResult = polylinePoints.decodePolyline(details.encodingPoints);

    pLineCoordinates.clear();

    if(decodedPolyLinePointsResult.isNotEmpty){
      decodedPolyLinePointsResult.forEach((PointLatLng pointLatLng) {

        pLineCoordinates.add(LatLng(pointLatLng.latitude,pointLatLng.longitude));
      });
    }
    polyLineSet.clear();

    setState(() {
      Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        color: Colors.pink,
        polylineId: PolylineId("PolylineID"),
        jointType: JointType.round,
        points: pLineCoordinates,
        width: 5,
        startCap: Cap.roundCap,endCap: Cap.roundCap,
        geodesic: true,
      );
      polyLineSet.add(polyline);

    });

    LatLngBounds latLngBounds;
    if(pickUpLatLng.latitude>dropOffLatLng.latitude && pickUpLatLng.longitude>dropOffLatLng.longitude){
      latLngBounds=LatLngBounds(southwest: dropOffLatLng, northeast: pickUpLatLng);
    }
    else if(pickUpLatLng.longitude>dropOffLatLng.longitude ){
      latLngBounds=LatLngBounds(southwest: LatLng(pickUpLatLng.latitude,dropOffLatLng.longitude),
          northeast:  LatLng(dropOffLatLng.latitude,pickUpLatLng.longitude));
    }

    else if(pickUpLatLng.latitude>dropOffLatLng.latitude ){
      latLngBounds=LatLngBounds(southwest: LatLng(dropOffLatLng.latitude,pickUpLatLng.longitude),
          northeast:  LatLng(pickUpLatLng.latitude,dropOffLatLng.longitude));
  }
    else {
      latLngBounds =LatLngBounds(southwest: pickUpLatLng, northeast: dropOffLatLng);
    }
    newgoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 70));
    Marker pickUpLocationMarker= Marker(
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueRed),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: initialPos.placeName,snippet: "my location"),
      position: pickUpLatLng,
      markerId: MarkerId("pickUpId"),
    );

    Marker dropOffLocationMarker= Marker(
      icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: finalPos.placeName,snippet: "DropOff Location"),
      position: dropOffLatLng,
      markerId: MarkerId("dropOffId"),
    );
    setState(() {
      markersSet.add(pickUpLocationMarker);
      markersSet.add(dropOffLocationMarker);
    });

    Circle pickUpLocCircle = Circle(
      fillColor: Colors.red,
      center: pickUpLatLng,
      radius: 12,
      strokeWidth: 4,
      strokeColor: Colors.redAccent,
      circleId: CircleId("pickUpId"),
    );
    Circle dropOffLocCircle = Circle(
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      center: pickUpLatLng,
      radius: 12,
      strokeWidth: 4,
      strokeColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      circleId: CircleId("dropOffId"),
    );
    setState(() {
      circlesSet.add(pickUpLocCircle);
      circlesSet.add(dropOffLocCircle);
    });

    }
}
```

Search Screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:topride/AllWidgets/Divider.dart';
import 'package:topride/Assistants/requestAssistant.dart';
import 'package:topride/DataHandler/appData.dart';
import 'package:topride/Models/address.dart';
import 'package:topride/Models/placePredictions.dart';
import 'package:topride/configMaps.dart';
import 'package:topride/AllWidgets/progressDialog.dart';


class SearchScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SearchScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchScreenState createState() => _SearchScreenState();
}

class _SearchScreenState extends State<SearchScreen> {

  TextEditingController pickUpTextEditingController= TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController dropOffTextEditingController= TextEditingController();
  List<PlacePredictions> placePredictionList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    String placeAddress= Provider.of<AppData>(context).pickUpLocation?.placeName ?? "";
        pickUpTextEditingController.text =placeAddress;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 215.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  blurRadius: 6.0,
                  spreadRadius: 0.5,
                  offset: Offset(0.7,0.7),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0,top: 25.0, right: 25.0,bottom: 20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back),
                      ),
                      
                      Center(
                        child: Text("Set Drop Off",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0,fontFamily: "Brand Bolt"),),

                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/pickicon.png",height: 16.0,width: 16.0,),
                      SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                      Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[400],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: pickUpTextEditingController,
                                decoration:InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "PickUp Location",
                                  fillColor: Colors.grey[400],
                                  filled: true,
                                  border: InputBorder.none,
                                  isDense: true,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11.0,top: 8.0,bottom: 8.0,),
                                ) ,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("images/desticon.png",height: 16.0,width: 16.0,),
                      SizedBox(width: 18.0),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[400],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                            child: TextField(

                              onChanged: (val){
                                findPlace(val);
                              },
                              controller: dropOffTextEditingController,
                              decoration:InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Destination",
                                fillColor: Colors.grey[400],
                                filled: true,
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                isDense: true,
                                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 11.0,top: 8.0,bottom: 8.0,),
                              ) ,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
             ),
          ),

          // tile for predictions

          (placePredictionList.length>0)? Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0,horizontal: 16.0),
            child: ListView.separated(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return PredictionTile(placePredictions: placePredictionList[index]);

              },
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context , int index)=> DividerWidget(),
              itemCount: placePredictionList.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            ),
          ) : Container()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  void findPlace(String placeName)async{
    if (placeName.length>1){
      String autoCompleteUrl ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$placeName&key=$mapkey&sessiontoken=1234567890&components=country:us";

      var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(autoCompleteUrl);
      if (res == "failed"){
        return ;
      }
     if(res["status"]=="OK"){
       var predictions=res["predictions"];
       var placesList = (predictions as List).map((e) => PlacePredictions.fromJson(e)).toList();

       setState(() {
         placePredictionList = placesList ;
       });
     }
    }
  }
}


class PredictionTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final PlacePredictions placePredictions;

   PredictionTile({Key key,this.placePredictions}) : super(key: key);



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return TextButton(

      onPressed: (){
        gtPlaceAddressDetails(placePredictions.place_id,context);
      },
      child: Container(
        child: Column(

         children: [
           SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
            Row(
             children: [
               Icon(Icons.add_location),
               SizedBox(width: 14.0,),
               Expanded(
                 child: Column(
                   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                   children: [
                     Text(placePredictions.main_text,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),),
                     SizedBox(height: 3.0,),
                     Text(placePredictions.secondary_text,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis ,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0,color: Colors.grey),),

                   ],
                 ),
               ),
             ],
           ),
           SizedBox(width: 10.0,),
         ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  void gtPlaceAddressDetails (String placeId,context)async{
    showDialog(context: context,

        builder: (BuildContext context)=> ProgressDialog (message:"Setting Drop Off ,please wait")
    );


    String placeDetailsUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$mapkey";
    var res = await RequestAssistant.getRequest(placeDetailsUrl);

    Navigator.pop(context);

    if(res=="failed"){
      return;

    }
    if(res["status"]=="OK"){
      Address address= Address();
      address.placeName=res["result"]["name"];
      address.placeId=placeId;
      address.latitude=res["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
      address.longitude=res["result"]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];

      Provider.of <AppData> (context,listen: false).updateDropOffLocationAddress(address);

      print("This is Drop Off Location :: ");
      print(address.placeName);
      Navigator.pop(context, "obtainDirection");
    }
  }
}
```

Flutter Run:

```
I/flutter ( 9764): This is Drop Off Location :: 
I/flutter ( 9764): Santa Clara
E/flutter ( 9764): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 9764): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 9764): Tried calling: [](0)
E/flutter ( 9764): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
E/flutter ( 9764): #1      AssistantMethods.obtainPlaceDirectionDetails (package:topride/Assistants/AssistantMethods.dart:51:49)
E/flutter ( 9764): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9764): #2      _MainScreenState.getPlaceDirection (package:topride/AllScreens/MainScreen.dart:323:19)
E/flutter ( 9764): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9764): #3      _MainScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:topride/AllScreens/MainScreen.dart:229:27)
E/flutter ( 9764): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 9764): 
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 7.337ms
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 19.440ms
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): Background young concurrent copying GC freed 69538(2560KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 26% free, 7194KB/9816KB, paused 5.012ms total 28.771ms
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): WaitForGcToComplete blocked HeapTrim on None for 6.576ms
I/Alqasim.TopRid( 9764): Background concurrent copying GC freed 84239(3130KB) AllocSpace objects, 17(1132KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 5486KB/10MB, paused 938us total 133.120ms
```

It shows no error when I'm coding but when I run the app it comes with this error when I choose an address and no encoded points in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using null safety? That can make this type of error easier to debug, though [migrating to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) takes a bit of effort.

In the short term, when null safety isn't being used, using `assert` can make null errors more readable.

That said, the error message is still pointing you to where `[]` is being called on null, on line 51 of AssistantMethods.dart.

There you'll find something like:

```
foo[0]
```

where foo is a variable that should be a list but is null at runtime.

Comment: No I'm not using null Safety ,I Actually did unsound null safety because of all problems I faced with it . if I sound it again this error will be solved??

Comment: Here is AssistantMethods:

Comment: AssistantMethods: line 51  :DirectionDetails directionDetails= DirectionDetails();
   directionDetails.encodingPoints= res["routs"][0]["overview_polyline"]["points"];

Comment: You're expecting that res["routs"] is a List, but it's null. Perhaps it's as simple as a typo. Did you mean to type "routes"?

Comment: oh my god! its a typo!!! thinks maaaaan a lot, its work!

Comment: I had the same typo when deserialising my googleplace response. This answer saved me after 2 wasted days. 

I've learnt sadly once again to take breaks intermittently during work to avoid bugs like this. Also it's best to copy the json value directly, instead of assuming you can spell it. Thanks man!